# Unable to add external email(s) in power bi RLS

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to add a user by email in the power bi app `RLS`. For this, I have created a `Role` and then publish the report online. Now I want to add the user. But I am unable to do it. Below is the screenshot

[image]

It clearly says the "One or more email addresses are outside your organization: gmail.com".

I have checked the admin portal the Invite to the external user is enabled.

[image]

I don't know what is the main reason, but I am stuck to it.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The external party obviously has no Power BI license (gmail.com). How they will login into Power BI to use this RLS is the first question, which you should ask yourself.

Comment: So how we can share with any other external group? Let say the party is using a desktop version.

Comment: Sharing is a Pro feature (i.e. both you and the recipient must have Power BI Pro licenses). To buy a Power BI license you need a busines e-mail address (hence gmail wont work), because it will create an Azure tenant with Azure Active Directory for this e-mail/domain name. If you just want to share something with them, why you are building a RLS? And it they will look at the report in Power BI Desktop, why not simply e-mail it to them (or share it as a file in any other way)?

Comment: Actually, the report has more than one companies data so we want to give read-only access to each company so they can only see their own report(s) not all.

Comment: We have a pro licenses.

Comment: You have Pro, but they don't. Also RLS works in Power BI Service, while you are saying they will view it in Power BI Desktop. There they can see all the data, modify your report (like removing RLS completely), see the data transformation (in Power Query Editor for example). You must either ask them to buy their own business e-mail (e.g. Microsoft 365) and Power BI Pro licenses for them, or to build an application and [embed the report for your customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=net-core).

Comment: @AndreyNikolov what if i create a user for my customers and then allow them to view ?